# How to add colour and legend in multiple line plot on ggplot without using melt from reshape package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am plotting two lines on same plot with sme x axis by following lines.
i am implementing the lower line but unable to see colors and legend

```
ggplot(final, aes(x = Date)) + geom_line(aes(y = cocastock)) + geom_line(aes(y = procterstock))  + scale_color_manual(values = c(cocastock = '#008B00', procterstock = '#FFFFFF'))
```

also tried

```
ggplot(final, aes(x = Date)) + geom_line(aes(y = cocastock)) + geom_line(aes(y = procterstock))  + scale_color_manual(values = c('#008B00','#FFFFFF'))
```

but dosen't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scale_colour_manual` only works when you have specified colour in `aes`, hence you need:

```
ggplot(final, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = cocastock, colour = "cocastock")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = procterstock, colour = "procterstock"))  + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cocastock = '#008B00', procterstock = '#FFFFFF'))
```